# Passing Table Cell Attributes to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button in a table cell that displays a Bootstrap modal dialog - this is working well. In the same table cell are some attributes that I would like to pass to the modal dialog.  Here's an example of the table cell:

```html
<td data-toggle="modal" productID="P1234" description="Lunchbox" data-skip-id="0" data-rec-id="61656" data-target="#showModal">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
</td>
```

I can get some of the attributes like the `data-rec-id` value using:

```
recID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('rec-id');
```

but can't work out the syntax to get others like the productID and description?

Also if I change the format of one of the attributes that is working, such as:

```
data-recID="61656"
```

then using:

```
recID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('recID');
```

doesn't seem to work either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`productId` and `description` are attributes directly on the element, so you need to use `attr()`:

```
var $td = $(e.relatedTarget);
var desc = $td.attr('description');
var productId = $td.attr('productId');
```

However, you should note that neither `productId` nor `description` are valid attributes for the `td` element. If possible, you should convert them to `data-*` attributes and use the same method to access them as you originally were, ie. `data()`